# calculating jslider progress bar in java

Tags: java

hello 
 i am developing an simple java audio player and i need to use jslider as progress bar and i used it while i play the progress bar finishes before the song has been finished i use this code

```
  Timer time = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
              int percent = 0;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    percent++;
                    if (percent>100)
                            percent = 0;

                 jSlider1.setValue((int)(100*(percent/600.0*duration)));
            }
    });
    time.start();
```

Comment: Why use a `JSlider` to mimic a `JProgressBar`?  Add a `MouseListener` to the progress bar and the user can easily reposition the track if needed.

Comment: hey!ME too trying to create media player

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I wouldn't keep a `percent` counter like that. I suggest you recompute the slider value **based on the starting time stamp** and **current time stamp**.

If your max value for the slider is 100 and `duration` represents the duration (in milliseconds) of the audio clip, you should be able to do

```
long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeStamp;
double percent = elapsed / duration;
jSlider1.setValue((int)(100*percent));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend making the max value of the slider equal to the duration of the track in seconds, because not only does it make the calculation easier (all you have to do is set the slider's position to the current duration rather than work out a percentage), but you get fine-grained control over the time position when reading and modifying the slider's position.  For example, a track which is a minute long will have a slider with 60 notches.  You'll also avoid rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your slider values range from 0 to 600, shouldn't the value be `600*percent`?

And shouldn't percent be calculated by `elapsedTime/duration`, e.g. `60/300` for the first minute of a 5 minute song?